# PHP - How do I go from a binary string to a blob in the database?

Tags: php

I have a binary string and I am trying to put it into the database. I do this by trying to unpack it to a binary array and then insert it into the database. But once I do that the blob column appears to be empty? I'm really stuck on this problem. $request->recording is the binary string.

[image]

[image]

**Var Dump looks like this, except it's way longer but I cut it off otherwise it would be too long**

> array(5177) {   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONCNq.png)=>   int(0)   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONCNq.png)=>
>   int(1)   [3]=>   int(0)   [4]=>   int(0)   [5]=>   int(0)   [6]=>
>   int(255)   [7]=>   int(255)   [8]=>

**Inserting into the database**

```
function insertIntoTable($connection, $tablename, $request)
{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT into $tablename(game_name, gamer_tag, meta_data, recording) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $byteArray = unpack('C*', $request->recording);
    var_dump($byteArray);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssb", $request->game_name, $request->gamer_tag, $request->meta_data, $byteArray);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error . " \r\n";
    }
}
```

**Base 64 encode results**

> string(1916)
>   "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"

Comment: Could it be your unpack params? Also whats the need to have a bytearray? A blob is supposed to be a *string*. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

Comment: What kind of string? If I put the binary string in there the column also remains empty. If I later perform a GET it will respond with a string(0). I did try to make a hex string and store it as a long text and then GET the long text and that worked fine. But I would really like to know how to store it as a Blob.

Comment: Good question. Next step is to determine how *blob* is to be formatted. But as a *string*. I don't know offhand. But seem its likely documented since hex works as a plain string. Seems that the bytearray introduced the empty field data problem. Oh your store the binary as long text im re-reading. Blob of course is better for your purposes. What does the docs say?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly have no clue where to look. I'm new to MySQL and I googled as much as I can and read the doc page you sent me but couldn't find anything about it. Every example is about storing an image or pdf and usually they don't show the string format.

Comment: Well storing an image or pdf would be great examples of binary data. Because the important thing is how to encode a normally ordinal 0 or null char' in *blob* that doesn't terminate the blob. In other words, the encoding of the blob is crucial.

Comment: I see them base64encoding images but it doesn't work for me. Would it help if you knew that the byte[] from a c# memory stream that serialized a serializable c# class ?

Comment: I posted the base64 encode results

Comment: What are the sizes of these recordings?  Because `BLOB` has a maximum of 65,535 bytes.  There's a decent chance the data is larger than what you set for the column size.  You might want a `LONGBLOB` instead.

Comment: It's only a few kb. I changed it to long blob for testing purposes tho and nothing changed.

Comment: Well.... I think I found the problem. When I changed the b to s in the bind_param it seems to work just fine. I think it makes sense because it's a string not a blob that gets inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `bind_param("sssb` because it shouldn't be a b but an s at the end. So like `bind_param("ssss` because i'm inserting a binary string and not a blob.